# No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: java, soap

Estoy tratando de consumir un servicio de tipo SOAP, lo pude generar correctamente las clases Java (Estoy usando Axis); sin embargo, me muestra el siguiente error:

org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: **No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory**
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.find(DiscoverClass.java:404) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45) ~[axis.jar:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41) ~[axis.jar:na]
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.(LogFactory.java:33) ~[axis.jar:na]
at org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.(BasicHandler.java:43) ~[axis.jar:na]
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104) ~[axis.jar:na]
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.(Service.java:113) ~[axis.jar:na]

Ya lo intente agregar los jar **org.apache.axis**, **axis**, **axis-wsdl4j**, **commons-logging** y **commons-discovery**; pero me sigue presentando el mismo error.

Alguna sugerencia sería de mucha ayuda. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver agregando el archivo **commons-logging.properties** en la carpeta **resources** (Spring-boot), dentro del archivo:

org.apache.commons.logging.Log = org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory = org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl

Comment: Me tira error cuando trato de levantar spring, tuviste que agregar una dependencia nueva, o algo?

Comment: Y no me anda en docker con el archivo...